# keep the order when filtering a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset ,`df`, as follow :

```
df = structure(list(filename = c("df1.txt", "df2.txt", "df3.txt", 
"df4.txt"), project = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"), lat = c(55.1852777777778, 
52.6252777777778, 51.446272, 50.688111), long = c(7.15138888888889, 
3.96027777777778, 1.078051, -0.343189)), row.names = c(NA, 4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I Would like to select 2 `filename` based on 2 given `project` :

```
selected = c("delta", "gamma")
```

To get the `filename` I'm using :

```
fname <- (df[df$project %in% selected,])$filename
```

But this will return `fname` as :

```
fname
[1] "df3.txt" "df4.txt"
```

Which the order is different by what I passed into the `selected` object !
I would like to get the `fname` as :

```
fname
[1] "df4.txt" "df3.txt"
```

since `df4` is referring to `delta` and `df3` is for `gamma` !
using `dplyr` and `filter` I'm getting the same result.
How could I get the output in the same order as input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` to get the position index to subset - `%in%` just returns a logical vector and thus it returns the subset values in the same order or occurrence in the data where there are `TRUE` values

```
> with(df, filename[match(selected, project)])
[1] "df4.txt" "df3.txt"
```

---

Or using `slice` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  slice(match(selected, project)) %>% 
  pull(filename)
[1] "df4.txt" "df3.txt"
```